# Distribution of Euclidean Distances Between Randomly Distributed Gaussian Points in n-Space

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry

I am interested in the distribution of Eucildean distance between two points in a $k$-dimensional space.

Fortunately I came across the following paper which is pretty good in deriving the CDF and PDF:

[Distribution of Euclidean Distances Between Randomly Distributed Gaussian Points in n-Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02238)

Unfortunately, I have troubles understanding some of the notations.

In particular the authors define the two points in a k-dimensional space as $\Gamma = (\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_k)$ and $\Psi = (\psi_1, \ldots, \psi_k)$.
However, later on the CDF is derived the following:
$$F(R, k) = 1 - \frac{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2}, \frac{R^2}{4})}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})}$$ in which $R$ seems to be defined as "the probability that the CDF is less than or equal to R". 
Taking aside the definition of $R$, the set $\Gamma$ seems suddenly to be a function with one or two inputs. The paper does not contain a definition of this function.

Hence my question, what does $\Gamma(x, y)$ and $\Gamma(x)$ return in this context?

Note: I tried to contact the original authors with out much success.

Comment: Perhaps the (generalized) Gamma functions - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function?

Comment: what if the Gaussians were not standard normal but some N(0,sigma^2). mean still 0 but not a unit variance. what would the result be in terms of the distrib? hope it doesnt change a tonne!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Calvin Lin suggested in the comments,

- $\Gamma(x) = \int\limits_0^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-t}\,dt$, the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), which for integer $x$ is $\Gamma(x)=(x-1)!$
- $\Gamma(x,y) = \int\limits_y^{\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt$, the upper [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

The work in your link looks a little excessive.  It is looking at the distribution of the distance between two independent standard multivariate normal random vectors.  If this is $k$-dimensional and the distance is $D$, then you could say that

- $\frac12 D^2$ has a [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with $k$ degrees of freedom
- $D^2$ has a [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with shape parameter $\frac k2$ and scale parameter $4$
- $\frac1{\sqrt 2} D$ has a [chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) with $k$ degrees of freedom
- $D$ has a [generalized gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution) with parameters  $p = 2$, $d = k$, and scale parameter $2$

and the moments of these are well known

Answer (score 0):

$F(R,k)=\mathbb{P}(\Vert X-Y\Vert\le R),$ where $X,\,Y\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $X,Y\sim N(0,I_k).$ That is, it is the cdf of the distance between two $k$-dimensional standard gaussian random variables.  Secondly, as pointed out in the comments, $\Gamma\left(\dfrac{k}{2},\dfrac{R^2}{4}\right)$ denotes the incomplete gamma function, and $\Gamma\left(\dfrac{k}{2}\right)$ is the standard gamma function.